# Where to place custom js files and how to reference them in Angular 4 application

Tags: javascript, angular

Let's say I acquired a html5 template. The folder that contains HTML, css, js files, and other types of resources like pictures. I copied/pasted the **Html** and **css** to **component.html** and **component.css**.

When it comes to JavaScript, I have a folder called **js** containing few individual **JavaScript** files.

Where should I place the js folder and how to do I reference them in my application?

In the original file I have something like all the way to the bottom of the HTML file:

```
<script src="js/script1.js"></script>
<script src="js/script2.js"></script>
<script src="js/script3.js"></script>
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: You can import the Javascript files in vendor.ts: `import "mypath/myfile.js";`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have two choices

## 1 you can place it inside body tag in index.html like this

```
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/script2.js">
</script>
</body>
```

## 2 you can place it inside scripts in .angular-cli.json file like this

```
"scripts": [
    "./assets/js/script2.js"
    "assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"
  ],
```

and if you want to access the code inside the component, declare a global variable just under the import statement and above the component declaration like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare const $: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'tc-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  showModal(){ 
  //caling jQuery method
   $("#modalId").show();
 }
}
```

Comment: materialize-css/ ??? is that an existing folder or I should create one with that name inside the assets folder?

Comment: @Richard77 that was just for example, anyway i updated with your sample js file.. you can create a folder called js inside assets and put the files there

Comment: I had that impression too it was just an example. However, I still don't understand: "declare const globalVar: any;..." which import? I'm sorry to keep asking. Can you add some more code to make your answer explicit?

Comment: @Richard77 let's say you are using jQuery.js and have to access the jjQuery code inside the angular component then refer my code I updated it

Comment: if my answer helped your question, could you accept it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 4):

You can put it under `src/assets/js/script1.js`

Then add it on `.angular-cli.json`

```
"apps": [
  {
    ...
    "scripts": [
      "assets/js/script1.js"
    ]
  }
]
```

To access your code on your typescript code,

you can access it globally via

```
declare const globalVar: any;
```